# How do I access my Truecrypt container?

Tags: release-freya, applications, mount, security, software-recommendation

I am migrating from OS X and have some Truecrypt containers that I want to access and eventually convert to Linux friendly containers. What solutions exists for elementary OS and is there one over the others?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just use TrueCrypt for Linux! Your containers will work!

Comment: It does work. Truecrypt was a bit hard to find, but Gibson Research Company seems to have trustworthy downloads. https://www.grc.com/misc/truecrypt/truecrypt.htm